# Simple rating math from model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I'm on my .cshtml page.

I have the math figured out for the average

```
@if (item.TRatings.Count() > 0)
{
    @Math.Ceiling(item.TRatings.Average(r => r.rating)) // returns 4
    <!-- fill in a star <i class="fa fa-star" style="color: yellow;"></i-->
}
else
{
    <!-- If 0 ratings then populate all stars black
    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star"></i> 
}
```

What I now need is a simple/clean way to fill in the star for the average number rounded up.

so for example in the above it returns 3.5 it should fill in 4 stars (unless there is an easy way to only fill in half the star through css) if not I'm ok with filling in 4 stars.

Comment: `Math.Ceiling` and `for loop` should help you

Comment: Yeah I got the rounding to work, I'm just having trouble figuring out the for loop.  Because I need 4 colored stars and one black star.  Not sure how or if I can put that into a single for loop or if I need two. @webdeveloper

Comment: Try something like this: `for(var i=0; i<5; i++){ if(i<average){ /*yellow*/} else { /*gray*/ } }`